# react native react-hook-form controller rules validation doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hook-form, react-forms

I have an application that I developed with react native. I'm using react-hook-form on both login and registration screens. and I have a validation schema that I created myself. I can't use this validation scheme with react-hook-form controller's rules because I can't assign input value please help!

```
const formKeys = {
    email: 'email',
    password: 'password',
  };

  const {
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    formState: {errors},
  } = useForm();

<Controller
                control={control}
                name={formKeys.email}
                render={({field: {onChange, value}}) => (
                  <InputFields
                    errorMessage={errors[formKeys.email]?.message.toString()}
                    value={value}
                    onChangeText={onChange}
                    autoCapitalize={'none'}
                    placeholder={t('common:email')}
                    image={
                      <View style={styles.userIconsStyle}>
                        <EmailIcon/>
                      </View>
                    }
                  />
                )}
                rules={{
                  required: emailValidation() //input value required here,
                  minLength: minLengthValidation(validationSchema.email.minLength),
                  maxLength:maxLengthValidation(validationSchema.email.maxLength),
                }}
              />

/*validation schema*/

export const emailValidation = (v: string): boolean | string => {
  const {t,i18n}=useTranslation();
  const emailRegx = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z]+$/;
  if (v) {
    return emailRegx.test(v) || `${t('common:errorMessages:invalidEmailAddress')}`;
  } else return `${t('common:email')} ${t('common:errorMessages:isRequired')}`;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a simple example with React js not React Native (will not be a different here)

```
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";

type FormValues = {
  email: string;
};

const emailValidation = (v: string): boolean | string => {
  // const {t,i18n}=useTranslation();
  const emailRegx = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z]+$/;
  if (v) {
    return emailRegx.test(v) || "invalidEmailAddress";
  } else return "isRequired";
};

export default function App() {
  const { handleSubmit, control, formState: {errors} } = useForm<FormValues>({mode: 'onChange'});

  console.log(errors);
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => console.log(data))}>
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name="email"
        render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value, ref } }) => (
          <input onChange={onChange} onBlur={onBlur} />
        )}
        rules={{
          validate: {
            required: (value) => emailValidation(value)
          },
        }}
      />

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-andras-bs7ogw?file=/src/App.tsx:0-971) example here

Comment: My bad. This doesn't work because use translation. thank u so much.

Comment: It should work with `useTranslation` too . Did you try adding `{mode: 'onChange'}`

Comment: yes I tried, but always the same error